# Integrating a Today Extension into a Codename One iOS App

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to this topic and couldn't find any guides concerning this. I'm wondering how the [Today Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html) files from a xcode project (originated from the CN1 iOS debug build sources) needs to be added to the actual CN1 project in order to get integrated properly.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have builtin support for that and didn't really study it. We never had official support for Android widgets either.

Both can be used through native code though. E.g. in this case you can use `ios.plistInject` to add the necessary plist changes. The actual UI/code that implements them should be done in a native interface anyway.

Comment: this doesn't work that way unfortunately as the extension's files need to get added in a specific folder to the resulting xcdoe project, plus the extension gets specified in the project's settings and currently it's not possible through the cn1 build hints.

Comment: You might be able to create the extension as a library or a POD and include it into the main project. If this doesn't work you can file an RFE with specific low level requirements e.g. the ability to place a specific file in a specific location. We already do that for various platforms.

Comment: this would have been a good workaround but this doesn't seem to be possible either. I'm going to make a RFE